# Can I use "widespreadly" as the adverbial form of "widespread"?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

When I wrote a post just now I came across a interesting problem. I tried to use "widespreadly" as the adverbial form of "widespread", but it was suggested a wrong word on my computer. I consulted a dictionary and couldn't find the word "widespreadly".

It seems quite normal to me to add *-ly* at the end of the adjective word "widespread" to make an adverbial word. Why is "widespeadly" not an established English word?

Comment: As a native English speaker I've never seen it/ it looks wrong to me. Could you give the context you tried to use it in?

Comment: The correct adverbial phrase is *widely spread*.

Comment: @ Luke Briggs, I intended to write, "The word is widespreadly used nowadays".

Comment: @dennylv I would phrase that as "The word is in widespread use nowadays" - I believe this would be the most common approach. Widely spread is for e.g. the gap between multiple things (usually data points).

Comment: @Mick: That isn't even a "correct" adverbial phrase. It contains an adverb, sure, but *widely spread* is an adjectival phrase. The only thing it can modify is a noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would say

> The **use** of the word is widespread nowadays.

and there **widespread** would be an adjectival modifier of the subject **use** attached to it by the predicate **is**.

**Widespread** is an interesting adjective. It's really a past-participle form, **spread**, with a sort of locative modifier **wide**, rolled up into a ball, as it were. If we untangle the ball we could say:

> The use of the word is **spread wide** nowadays.

P.S. Compare **parboiled**, **overdone**.