# What happened to "widely spread"?

Tags: construction

According to statistics and Google Ngram [**"widely spread"**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=widely+spread&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwidely%20spread%3B%2Cc0) is dying out, and is being used less and less often while [**"widespread"**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=widespread&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwidespread%3B%2Cc0) is becoming popular.

There's also [**"spreads widely"**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spreads+widely&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspreads%20widely%3B%2Cc0) that is also correct but becoming less popular.

Comment: *Widely spread* was never ['popular'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=widely+spread%2Cwidespread%2Cspread+widely%2Cspread+wide&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwidely%20spread%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwidespread%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspread%20widely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspread%20wide%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Are you sure? I've seen it in books and articles.

Comment: 'Popular' does not mean 'used on occasion'. But look at the link I gave.

Comment: related: [Is there a rule which may indicate us when to use “BROAD” and when to use “WIDE”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110426/is-there-a-rule-which-may-indicate-us-when-to-use-broad-and-when-to-use-wide) and [Can I use “widespreadly” as the adverbial form of “widespread”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110648/can-i-use-widespreadly-as-the-adverbial-form-of-widespread)